# Does Google Documents List API support OAuth 2

Tags: oauth-2.0

The documentation currently does not mention OAuth 2. However, I was hoping the docs are out date, and that someone has gotten OAuth 2 to work with the Document List API. Even the Spreadsheet API supports it, so I'm having wishful thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that support is in beta. Use scope=https://docs.google.com/feeds/